# Multiple order by with join

Tags: php, orm, fuelphp

I am new to fuelphp.Need to add `order_by` for parent table: `order by username asc, parent_table_field asc`. I tried following code:

```
Model_Definition::find('all',
Array
(
[related] => Array
    (
        [users] => Array
            (
                [order_by] => Array
                    (
                        [username] => asc
                    )

            )

    )
 [order_by] => Array
 (
     [parent_table_field] => asc
 )
[rows_limit] => 50
[rows_offset] => 0
)
)
```

But it applies order by for parent-table's field first and then for username.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not control the way the query is generated using array notation.

You'll have more control with method chaining, which will apply the order_by clauses in the sequence in which they are defined.